# Half hour time zones missing

Tags: php, date

In PHP I am using `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` to get a list of time zones for user selection. This seems to be working fine, but missing from this list are the half hour time zones.

Notably Newfoundland, Iran and India. Anyone know how to get them back, why they are missing? The [PHP docs show them as "don't use these timezones"](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) but they are still used in the world and they don't seem to be listed in [the "valid" list anywhere here.](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, *Australia/Adelaide* is an half-hour offset zone and it's in the list so the whole half-hour thing is not the cause

Comment: @RobbieAverill this question came first so that one is the duplicate

Answer (score 2):

For example:

Newfoundland time zone identifier is `America/St_Johns`

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, but it looks like the default `$what` parameter is `DateTimeZone::ALL`, and you want to use identifiers that only exist now for backwards compatibility - so you should use [`DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php#datetimezone.constants.all-with-bc):

```
print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC));
```

Note that [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) does say not to use them.

In the case of Iran, you could replace it with the Asia/Tehran time zone for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I overlooked a few of the half hour timezones when scanning the list of 420 or so. The end result of this is that, yes the timezones are there. In the IANA list they all changed away from their historic names.

There seems to be a subtle distinction in how IANA meant the linked timezones to be used and how PHP implemented it exactly that is now in the realm of "definitely not a bug, but clear as mud in the docs" and that has a sort of solution.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66102

This Github search made it much clearer also:
https://github.com/eggert/tz/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Newfoundland

So, they are there. I still have some concerns about usability and whether our users will understand to choose America/St_Johns and the like when looking for their timezones. We are doing some research with our users about that.