# Converting IST datetime to Asia/Kolkata datetime adds 3.5 extra hours in PHP DateTime's setTimezone() procedure

Tags: php, datetime

I have a piece of code

```
$data = array(
  'fromTimezone'          => 'IST',
  'toTimezone'            => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  'dateTime'              => '2020-04-19 16:23:00',
  'dateTimeFormat'        => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
);

$fromTimezone           = $data['fromTimezone'];
$toTimezone             = $data['toTimezone'];
$dateTime               = $data['dateTime'];
$dateTimeFormat         = $data['dateTimeFormat'];


$fromZoneDateTime    = new DateTime($dateTime, new DateTimeZone($fromTimezone));

// synchronizing with the to-Timezone
$fromZoneDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($toTimezone));

$returnDateTime    = date($dateTimeFormat, strtotime($fromZoneDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
echo $returnDateTime;
```

As you can see, I am converting timezone from IST to Asia/Kolkata. Basically, Asia/Kolkata is IST (Indian Standard Time) and hence, they both should have same time. But the aresult I am getting is `2020-04-19 19:53:00`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:-

One may ask me why do I need to convert to IST to Asia/Kolkata. Fact is, in Laravel app, our default timezone is Asia/Kolkata. But in mysql query, I am getting the timezone as 'IST'.

```
SELECT IF(@@session.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@session.time_zone) AS mysql_timezone;
```

In user table, a user's timezone is saved as 'Asia/Kolkata', 'America/NewYork', etc which is sent from the mobile app.

In my tables, there is a field called `created_date` (not to be confused with `created_at`) which saves current date time by using PHP's `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` procedure. So when I am trying to convert this to user's timezone, I am converting it from IST to Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: It looks like that would be one of the half-hour timezones. Here is more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261668/half-hour-time-zones-missing

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India) Asia/Kolkata us UTC+5:30 which is where you're getting the half-hour time difference.

> The Republic of India uses one time zone, which is Indian Standard Time (IST). This is UTC+05:30 — that is, five and a half hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time. ... The IANA time zone database contains only one zone, namely Asia/Kolkata.

**Additional Info**

According to [the docs on PHP timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php):

> Warning
>   Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons, and may expose erroneous behavior.
>
> Warning
>   If you disregard the above warning, please also note that the IANA timezone database that provides PHP's timezone support uses POSIX style signs, which results in the Etc/GMT+n and Etc/GMT-n time zones being reversed from common usage.
>
> For example, the time zone 8 hours ahead of GMT that is used in China and Western Australia (among other places) is actually Etc/GMT-8 in this database, not Etc/GMT+8 as you would normally expect.
>
> Once again, it is strongly recommended that you use the correct time zone for your location, such as Asia/Shanghai or Australia/Perth for the above examples.

Comment: But the list don't have IST in the list at all. Asia/Kolkata is a valid timezone and listed in Laravel too. Besides, when I am coverting timezone from Asia/Kolkata to GMT+5:30, I am getting correct timezone data. So I think the problem lies with IST notion. But then, why isn't PHP showing me any error?

Comment: Yes, I just provided the additional information as a reference. Asia/Kolkata is a valid timezone and there is no need to convert to IST because they are the same.